# How to check your path in Command Prompt

Tags: laravel, command-prompt

I'm learning Laravel and found this direction on their documentation:

"Make sure to place the ~/.composer/vendor/bin directory in your PATH so the laravel executable is found when you run the laravel command in your terminal." http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/installation#install-laravel

Question:

1. How exactly I make sure the folder is on my PATH? What's the command?
2. If I'm not on the PATH, how to get there? I tried to find /.composer/vendor/bin but got nothing.

I'm using Windows 8 64bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) windows: `PATH | grep -oP ".composer.*bin"`

If it's in the path You'll get a response if it's not you'll get nothing.

2)
`~/` refers to home path on linux doing `%HOMEPATH%` on windows results in the same thing, which in your case would be `%HOMEPATH%/.composer/vendor/bin`

Doing `/somefolder` Will go to the root path in linux and try to find a folder there called `somefolder` but won't do anything in windows, I'm not sure what the equivalent in windows is, might be referring to root of the drive, I.e. `C:\` or `D:\` etc.

To add `.composer/vendor/bin` to your home path you need to go to your environmental variables and add it into the path you can go [here](https://superuser.com/questions/502358/easier-way-to-change-environment-variables-in-windows-8) and follow the steps in the answer or the question.

The important bit:

> Example of windows SETX command:
>
> Print the PATH environment variable:
>
> C:\Users\Charity>echo %PATH% C:\windows\system32;C:\windows and
>   space;C:\foobar Use setx to set the environment variable:
>
> C:\Users\Charity>setx PATH "%PATH%;C:\zombiepoke" SUCCESS: Specified
>   value was saved. Close and re-open cmd terminal, then run:
>
> C:\Users\Charity>echo %PATH% C:\windows\system32;C:\windows and
>   space;C:\foobar;C:\zombiepoke You have to be careful with double
>   quotes. If you let quotes get into your path variable it might break
>   something. However they are necessary for specifying addendums to the
>   original %PATH%.

Make note though that this only sets it for the current user context, to set it for all users you have to to use `setx /M`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering, I tried to input the command "grep" but it says 'grep' is not recognized as internal or external command. Am I doing it right?

Comment: Oh crap, I apologise. I forgot that I have gow installed which gives me access to unix utilities and grep doesn't come standard. You can install gow from here: https://github.com/bmatzelle/gow/wiki . I did look at the windows equivalent called `findstr` but I can't seem to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

for those who also needs the answer for this question, I found it here.

Basically, all you need is to write:

```
cd %APPDATA%\Composer\vendor\bin
```